# How do you count characters of a textarea within a dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                   
function createDialog(text, id) {
    return $("<div class='dialog'><textarea id='textarea' class ='texbox' name='textarea' value='text'>" + text + "</textarea></div>"
      .dialog({
        dialogClass: "dialogStyle",
        title: "Edit Description",
        resizable: false,
        position: {
          my: "right+240 top-200",
          at: "center",
          of: $("body"),
          within: $("body")
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Save": function() {
            var product = $(this).find('textarea [name="textarea"]').val();
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $("#" + id).val(product);
          },
          Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        },
        overlay: {
          opacity: 0.5,
          background: "black"
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

How do i incorporate a character count with max 255 characters for the textarea within the dialog box?
I've looked around for code but placing it within the function createDialog won't work and getting length variable doesn't work either when putting it inside the dialog.

Comment: Add a `keyup` handler for the textarea that counts the characters.

Comment: Validate it before permitting the "Saving", too (i.e. clicking save causes validation before further action)

Comment: Can you please explain, how the question is related to `css`, `oracle` or `apex`?

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. i guess my question would be where in the code do i insert the keyup handler?

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, that's a good tip. I'll definitely add that in. thank you

Comment: @Teemu sorry, this is within oracle apex, and i added css because there is css that i used. But not pertaining to this problem... so my bad on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your dialog to include a DIV for the count:

```
    return $("<div class='dialog'><textarea id='textarea' class ='texbox' name='textarea' value='text'>" + text + "</textarea><div>Characters: <span class='charcount'>0</span></div></div>"
```

Then add the following JS:

```js
$(document).on("keyup edit paste", ".dialog .texbox", function(e) {
    var charcount = $(this).val().length;
    if (charcount > 255) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    $(this).closest(".dialog").find(".charcount").text(charcount);
});

function createDialog(text, id) {
  return $("<div class='dialog'><textarea id='textarea' class ='texbox' name='textarea' value='text' placeholder='"+text+"'></textarea><div>Characters: <span class='charcount'>0</span></div></div>")
    .dialog({
      dialogClass: "dialogStyle",
      title: "Edit Description",
      resizable: false,
      position: {
        my: "right+240 top-200",
        at: "center",
        of: $("body"),
        within: $("body")
      },
      height: 200,
      width: 300,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
          var product = $(this).find('textarea[name="textarea"]').val();
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $("#" + id).val(product);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      overlay: {
        opacity: 0.5,
        background: "black"
      }
    });

}

$("#button").click(function() {
    createDialog("This is a message", "foo");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Show dialog</button>
<input id="foo"/>
```

Comment: I would bind to other events as well. Keyup won't trigger for non-keyboard triggered changes to the value... ie, pasting, cutting, etc.

Comment: adding the above wouldn't pop the dialog box up anymore, it does this for other attempts that i've done.

Comment: Adding the above doesn't change the code that pops up the dialog.

Comment: I was using the wrong types of quotes in my added HTML, so it was getting a syntax error. I've fixed it. I'm not sure why your Save and Cancel buttons aren't showing up, though.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much!!! It's exactly what I was looking for.

By any chance, would you happen to know if it's possible to do a character count that look like this: "(0/255)" on the title of the dialog box? Next to "Edit Description"?

Comment: @Barmar So, it works in terms of the charcount but now when i click on Save, it completely erases the value of what was initially in the field that calls createDialog. Whether or not it's < or > 255 chars... clicking save doesn't grab the updated values of textarea anymore when i have the above code.

Comment: You had a typo in the selector. `$("textarea [name=textarea]") should have been `$("textarea[name=textarea]"). Try it now.

Comment: I've changed from putting the argument text as the initial value to putting it in the placeholder, so the user doesn't have to erase it himself.

Comment: @Barmar It finally works to the fullest, added some extra functionality on top of it! Thank you so much for providing the foundation!!! Great help!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use delegation for this.  You could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('input propertychange', '#textarea', function() {
    var text = $('#textarea').val();

    if (text.length > 255) {
        $('#textarea').val(text.substring(0,255));
    }

    //Maybe some code to display a message to the user, or update a character count element or something?
});
```

Comment: hmm. I must be doing something wrong. text still goes over 255